# Access data object activiti 5

Tags: activiti

How can I access the Data Objects in Activiti in Java API?

```
List<ProcessInstance> instanciasProcedimientos = runtimeService
            .createProcessInstanceQuery().list();
    System.out
            .println(instanciasProcedimientos.size());


    for (ProcessInstance processInstance : instanciasProcedimientos) {
        System.out.println(processInstance.toString());
    }
```

Comment: I use 5.22 version

Comment: What does that mean? What is a Data Object? Usually, that means process variables, so try processInstance.getVariables(); Have you checked the documentation in activiti.org?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  the Documentation says: BPMN provides the possibility to define data objects as part of a process or sub process element. According to the BPMN specification it’s possible to include complex XML structures that might be imported from XSD definitions. As a first start to support data objects in Activiti the following XSD types are supported.The data object definitions will be automatically converted to process variables using the name attribute value as the name for the new variable. In addition to the definition of the data object.

Comment: Exactly, so you access them as process variables, right?

Comment: Yes, now i can access to them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this question is: processInstance.getVariables();